# See attributes of currently connected Ldap user

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I connect to an LDAP server as Bob:

```
Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Bob,cn=Users,dc=myCompany,dc=com");
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Password1");
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
InitialLdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(props, null);
```

Now I want to see Bob's name and email address.

I was expecting to find a method on `context` to return the attributes of the currently connected user, but I can't find one.

Bob doesn't have permission to search the directory, so I can't use `context.search` after connecting.

Is there a way to get these attributes without making another call to the LDAP server, or having to connect as someone else first?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [RFC 4532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4532) 'whoami' extended operation, OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.11.3. You'll need to write yourself an `ExtendedRequest` and `ExtendedResponse` class for that (sorry can't post mine, but it's simple), and use it as follows:

```
WhoAmIExtendedResponse  response = (WhoAmIExtendedResponse)context.extendedOperation(new WhoAmIExtendedRequest());
```

and then get the authZId out of the response. That's the DN of the current user, prefixed by `"dn:"`. You then get his attributes via `context.getAttributes("...")`